# Google cloud hosted Website down (Cloudflare 522) and no contacts for support

Tags: google-cloud-platform

The website of one of my clients is down, Cloudflare error 522. The Google agency in our country is no more existing and he has no admin user for G-Suite or filing an issue in the google cloud console.
Any ideas how to contact the Google support?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. It seems to be off-topic, but if you want to contact Google Cloud Support, [click here](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Free trial account you can have chat support through  [Console Support Center](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/chat?_ga=2.201203500.305402083.1598273128-638966553.1591892739), also, you can visit the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/support) for more information.

Additionally, you could contract a [Support plan](https://cloud.google.com/support#) in order to have cases for technical support through phone, and chat.

---

Also, for the error you mentioned, you could find useful the following information:

#### Quick Fix Ideas

1. Make sure that you’re *not blocking Cloudflare IPs* in .htaccess, iptables, or your firewall.
2. Make sure your *hosting provider isn’t rate limiting* or blocking IP requests from the Cloudflare IPs and ask them to whitelist the IP addresses here: https://www.cloudflare.com/ips . If the IPs that fail are consistent each time, that indicates some of the IPs in Cloudflare’s IP ranges are either being rate-limited or blocked by a network device at your hosting provider. Because Cloudflare operates as a reverse proxy the IP address your server will see is one of a limited number of Cloudflare IPs. In that sense, many actual visitors may all come from the same IP address, which can cause firewalls or security software that is not appropriately whitelisting the Cloudflare IP ranges to block this traffic as it may see it as excessive or malicious
3. If you are seeing 522 errors in *certain locations only*, it means you likely forgot to whitelist one of our ranges that corresponds to these locations, so double check to ensure all our IPs are whitelisted appropriately.
4. Please reach out to your hosting provider or site administrator to confirm if there are any load problems on your infrastructure.
5. It may be there was a temporary problem on the path or at your origin preventing connections from completing. If they are no longer happening, here are two actions to take: a) Check with your hosting provider to see if they had any issues with packet loss or if your server was under load at the time the errors happened and b) Have your hosting provider or server administrator confirm that all Cloudflare IP ranges are fully whitelisted from any rate limits.
6. If your firewall is configured to DROP packets rather than refuse connections, it will cause a 521; meaning an incorrectly configured firewall can actually masquerade as a connection timeout 522 error.

Finally, I have found the following [documentation](https://support.exabytes.com.my/en/support/solutions/articles/14000100761-error-522-connection-timed-out#:%7E:text=Overview,and%20the%20request%20times%20out.&text=Check%20that%20the%20origin%20web,your%20Cloudflare%20account%20are%20correct.) that can help you to troubleshoot your issue.